# What is the French word for handwash as in soap?

Tags: vocabulaire

What is the French word for handwash as in soap?

https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBGB731GB731&ei=pg_WWpa7MoyUgAbUjICgCA&q=define+hand+wash&oq=define+hand+wash&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l3j0i22i30k1l7.4791412.4797443.0.4798199.15.12.3.0.0.0.98.887.12.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.15.898...0i67k1j0i10k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.ftvNaTLneOc

Answer (score 1):

We simply call it  *savon liquide*.

Comment: And most of the time, we'd rather talk about "soap", simply.

Comment: @avazula I guess you mean we might just say *savon*, dropping *liguide*.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. it's for the familiar simplification :)

Comment: So are you guys saying it's either savon liquide or savon? And that savon is more commonly used?

Comment: Yes, there is no common and specific name for soap intended to be used to wash hands but should you really need to specify it: ***Savon [liquide] pour les mains***.